Barycenter of a triangle using integration 2
Problem definition
Consider a triangle with vertices $\{V_i=[\xi_i\,\,\eta_i]'\}_{i=1}^3$. As is well known, the barycenter (or centroid) $g$ of a triangle coincides with the mean of its vertices, so that \begin{equation} g\triangleq\frac{V_1+V_2+V_3}{3} \end{equation}
I want to show that the barycenter is the solution of the following "continuous average"
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{g}\triangleq \frac{\int_{\partial\mathcal{T}} z \text{ d}z}{\int_{\partial\mathcal{T}} \text{d}z} = \frac{\int_0^1 z(\alpha) \lVert \dot{z}(\alpha)\rVert \text{ d}\alpha}{\int_0^1 \lVert \dot{z}(\alpha)\rVert \text{ d}\alpha}
\end{equation*}
where $\partial\mathcal{T}\subseteq{\mathbb{R}^2}$ is the set of points $z$ belonging the triangle perimeter and $z(\alpha):[0,1]\mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ is a parametrization of $\partial T$. Moreover, I use the notation $\dot{z}(\alpha)\triangleq \frac{\text{d}z}{\text{d}\alpha}(\alpha)$ to denote the vector tangent to $\partial T$.
I want to prove $\tilde{g}=g$.
My attempt
In order to compute such integral I want to use the following specific parametrization
\begin{equation*}
z(\alpha)\triangleq \begin{cases}
\frac{V_2-V_1}{L_1} L \left(\alpha-\frac{\tau_0}{L}\right)+V_1 & \alpha\in[\tau_0/L, \tau_1/L)\\
\frac{V_3-V_2}{L_2} L \left(\alpha-\frac{\tau_1}{L}\right)+V_2 & \alpha\in[\tau_1/L, \tau_2/L)\\
\frac{V_1-V_3}{L_3} L \left(\alpha-\frac{\tau_2}{L}\right)+V_3 & \alpha\in[\tau_2/L, \tau_3/L]\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where, using the convention $V_4\triangleq V_1$, I introduced the following terms
\begin{equation*}
L_i \triangleq \lVert V_{i+1}-V_i \rVert \qquad L\triangleq L_1+L_2+L_3 \qquad \tau_i \triangleq \sum_{j=1}^{i} L_j \qquad \tau_0\triangleq 0.
\end{equation*}
Using such parametrization, the tangent vector norm simplifies as
\begin{equation*}\lVert \dot{z}(\alpha) \rVert =L \qquad \alpha\in[0,1]\end{equation*}
so that the barycenter reduces to
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\tilde{g}&= \int_0^1 z(\alpha) \text{ d}\alpha= \sum_{i=1}^3 \int_{\tau_{i-1}/L}^{\tau_i/L}
\frac{V_{i+1}-V_i}{L_i} L \left(\alpha-\frac{\tau_{i-1}}{L}\right)+V_i \text{ d}\alpha \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^3  \left[(V_{i+1}-V_i)\frac{L}{L_i} \int_{\tau_{i-1}/L}^{\tau_i/L} 
\alpha-\frac{\tau_{i-1}}{L} \text{ d}\alpha+ V_i \underbrace{\int_{\tau_{i-1}/L}^{\tau_i/L} 
 \text{ d}\beta}_{=\frac{\tau_{i}-\tau_{i-1}}{L}=\frac{L_i}{L}}\right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Now, for integral in $\text{d}\alpha$, holds
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\tau_{i-1}/L}^{\tau_i/L} 
\alpha-\frac{\tau_{i-1}}{L} \text{ d}\alpha= \int_0^{\frac{\tau_i}{L}-\frac{\tau_{i-1}}{L}}
\gamma \text{ d}\gamma=\int_0^{\frac{L_i}{L}}
\gamma \text{ d}\gamma=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{L_i}{L}\right)^2
\end{equation*}
hence,
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\tilde{g}&=\sum_{i=1}^3 \left(\frac{V_{i+1}-V_i}{2} + V_i\right)\frac{L_i}{L}= \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{V_{i+1}+V_i}{2}\frac{L_i}{L}\\
&=\frac{L_3+L_1}{2L} V_1+ \frac{L_1+L_2}{2L} V_2 + \frac{L_2+L_3}{2L} V_3
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
which is not equal to $g\triangleq (V_1+V_2+V_3)/3$. Did I make any mistakes?
EDIT
It makes more sense to write
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{g} = \frac{L_1}{L} \frac{V_2+V_1}{2} +
\frac{L_2}{L} \frac{V_3+V_2}{2}+
\frac{L_3}{L} \frac{V_1+V_3}{2}
\end{equation*}
which is a mixture of the three median points $\frac{V_2+V_1}{2}$, $\frac{V_3+V_2}{2}$, $\frac{V_1+V_3}{2}$, where each weight is proportional of the respective edge length. Hence, I believe that my calculation of $\tilde{g}$ is correct and in general holds $\tilde{g} \neq g$.
